# Automatic prompt for nationality/citizenship for Visa questions

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Would it be possible and desirable to have some automatic prompt for visa-related questions (determined either by use of the visas tag, or just the word visa in the text) reminding question askers to please include their citienship/nationality in the question? It's relevant the vast majority of the time, yet many question askers neglect to include this key information.

Comment: +1, I have seen this a lot.  Any ideas why people do not include their nationality?

Comment: @GayotFow most often they seem to expect us to just know. Not thinking about this being an international website I guess. Other than that forgetfulness, not thinking it matters, etc.

Comment: A feature request can get political and time consuming. Alternatively, would it be helpful to compose a question/answer pair like "what information do I need in order to get a high quality answer?"  And then start dropping the link in comments to each OP.

Comment: A simple overlay alert like put your passport nationality in question could be done when the person clicks submit.   Then on the second submit, a checkbox could be revealed that says 'I mentioned nationality already'

Answer (score 6):

In meta sites, you have to add one of the following tags: [feature-request](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), [discussion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug). That's a start..

If SE team can make it mandatory to have a [xyz-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xyz-citizens) with some selected tags, such as [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas), [transit-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit-visas), etc.. this would be awesome, it does not have to be a hard rule, it can be a message where the user has to click OK or something.

I do not know if this is technically possible, does SE have an audit logic which can be customized for each site? not sure.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be a prompt (whether pop-up or just a note appearing somewhere), not an actual barrier to posting.

Comment: It would have to be a prompt, because there are only 36 [tag:xyz-citizens] tags currently and many of the people who need this prompt wouldn't have the rep to create a new one.

Comment: @peter good point!